# Create dynamic names for lists

Tags: python, list, csv, python-3.x

From a `shapefile` I create a number of `csv files` but I don't know how many of them will be created each time. The `csv files` are named `road_1`, `road_2` etc.
In these files, I have coordinates. I would like to put the coordinates of every csv files in lists.

So for `road_1` I would like 3 lists: 
`x_1, y_1, z_1`
For road_2:
`x_2, y_2, z_2` etc.

I tried to name the lists in the loop where I get the coordinates with this : `list+'_'+i` where i is iterating through the number of files created, but i cannot concatenate a list and a string.

**

### EDIT

**

Ok, some marked this topic as duplicated, fair enough. But just saying that I have to use a dictionnary doesn't answer all of my question. I had thought of using a dictionnary but my main issue is creating the name (either the name of the list, either the key of a dictionnary). I have to create this in a loop, not knowing how many I have to create. Thus, the name of the list (or key) should have a variable which must be the number of the road. And it's here that I have a problem.

As I said before, in my loop i tried to use a variable from the iteration loop to name my list but this didn't work, since it's not possible to concanate list with string. I could create an empty dictionnary with many empty key:value pairs, but I would still have to go through the keys name in the loop to add the values from the csv file in the dict.

Comment: You could also provide some code youve tried. That might make more clear what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Since it has been asked many times I wont write the code but only point you in the right direction (and maybe a different approach).

Use the [glob](http://pymotw.com/2/glob/) module which will return the file names. Something like:

```
import glob
for csvFileNames in glob.glob("dir/*.csv"):
```

will return you each filename into the variable `csvFileNames`.

Then you simply open you `csv Files` with something like:

```
with open(csvFileNames, "r") as filesToRead:
    for row in filestoRead:
        #the structure of you csv File is unknown so cannot say anything here
```

Then its simple. Find you columns your interested in and create a dicts with the variables you need as keys. Use a counter to increment. All the information is there!

Comment: My main issue is with the naming! How to create names for list (or for dict keys) that contains the number of the road (without knowing how many roads are there beforehand) ?

Comment: @guy16 Just as I wrote. When you use the `glob` library the **name** of the csv File(s) in the folder will be returned. It goes through the folder from top to bottom (like a loop). Like this, each name is once in the variable `csvFileNames` which you then can use as dict key i.e. :)

Comment: Okay, but for each filename i need 3 list (x, y & z). Thus i can only use the filename as dict key for one list. That's why i thought of naming the list according to the number of file, but i'm stuck at this point :/

Comment: @guy16 simply put a counter in your loop which increments after you read the column you needed to read?